# How to have output on one line in javascript

Tags: javascript

I know this is probably so simple but I have tried `/s` to get spaces between my words.`document.write('You have been alive' + */s userMsDays  /s* +  'days');`

I have tried +''+ to have code output to one line `document.write('<li><font color="red">emotional:</font></li>'  + *''+ bioEmot +''*);`

Comment: What's `*/s` and `/s*` supposed to be?

Comment: @tjameson `/s` can be used in regular expressions to denote a space character. I think that's where he got it from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply input the spaces inside the string:

```
document.write('You have been alive ' + userMsDays + ' days');
```

Comment: when i tried to use the italic button it put the * before and after. Thank you  for that,I know have my sapces but do you know how to have this      document.write('<li><font color="red">emotional:</font></li>' + bioEmot );    appear on one line instead of two

Comment: ok i put () around bioEmot and that put that all up on one line but took away the list point. So now have output as : emotional:0.8. So not sure how to fix.

Comment: @ David sorry I didn't see your comment, and was so excited that I thought I had fixed it, I posted and then felt like an idiot when it still didn't work, so came back and deleted last two posts.   The <li> point in front of the output

Comment: @Sonya1m You should post that as a separate question.